# jsf commandbutton confirm don't show any message

Tags: java, jsf, confirm

I have a `<h:commandButton>` on my page connected with action in my bean. It work just fine, but I wanted to add confirmation message. When I used:
`<h:commandButton onclick="confirm('Are you sure?')">`
 
it alco works just fine. But when I try to get string from bean, by making it looks like this:
`<h:commandButton onclick="confirm('#{bean.confirmQ}')">` 
it doesn't display this string. In getter for this string I invoke method to take some info from DB, and I format it then I return it. When I use this approach nothing is shown, not even empty box, and page looks like just refreshing.

Here is code from bean:

```
private String confirmQ;

public String getConfirmQ() {
    WycenioneAuta wa = getWycenioneAuto();
    String question = "are you sure \n" + wa.getName + "?";
    confirmQ = question;
    return confirmQ;
}

public void setConfirmQ(String confirmQ) {
    this.confirmQ = confirmQ;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `#{bean.confirm}` anywhere in your page to check if the message is properly written there?

Comment: Yes - I fired my app in debug mode, and message is rendered correctly - I even copy it's value and paste it into confirm bracket, and then it is rendered. But from bean there's not even a box rendered.

Comment: I mean if you used something like `<h:outputText value="#{bean.confirm}" />` to see if the message gets printed in your page.

Comment: I just did it, and message is printed correctly

Comment: But your getter says `confirmQ`. Where is `confirm` supposed to come from?

Comment: Great eye @kolossus, but it is just a type'o. I edited the post, and now it's just like my code. Still - thanks for taking time to try to solve my problem:)

Comment: @LuciusSnow - the symptoms indicate a javascript error, most likely because JSF won't evaluate EL in any of the `onXXX` callbacks. Look in your javascript console to confirm

Comment: @kolossus The EL will be evaluated when the page is being rendered. So when the user clicks the button, the text to be confirmed should already be in the code. The code posted so far should work and the problem is probably somewhere else. Checking your javascript console for errors will give you the solution I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Escape the line by writing  `String question = "are you sure \\n" + wa.getName + "?";`
2. If your String variable is confirmQ , then the right EL pointing to that variable is `#{bean.confirmQ}` and not `#{bean.confirm}` as you've written.

Comment: well, I just hate when the problem is so silly :/ Thanks for help and good luck:)

Comment: I understand , we all do that at some point :) You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In complement to ஜன்'s Answer:

At least for Firefox , I should had a *return* in the Javascript code, otherwise the *cancel* does not work:

```
<h:commandButton onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" ... />
```